# Haskell: Conflicting definitions in case

Tags: haskell

I am getting `Conflicting definitions for 'boardSize'` in `isCornerPos` but not `isCornerPos'`. Why?

```
boardSize :: Int
boardSize = 8

isCornerPos :: Position -> Bool
isCornerPos (i, j) =
    case (i, j) of
        (1, 1)                  -> True
        (1, boardSize)          -> True
        (boardSize, 1)          -> True
        (boardSize, boardSize)  -> True -- problem with this line
        _ -> False

isCornerPos' :: Position -> Bool
isCornerPos' (i, j) =
    case (i, j) of
        (1, 1) -> True
        (1, 8) -> True
        (8, 1) -> True
        (8, 8) -> True
        _ -> False
```

Comment: You're trying to use the same name for two different variables. You seem to think that `boardSize` refers to the `boardSize` identifier defined above. It does not. It is a pattern variable that has nothing to do with the `boardSize = 8` above.

Comment: I see, but I want to avoid hard-coding. I guess I need `i>= 1 && i <= boardSize` etc...

Comment: oops  `i == 1 && j == boardSize` etc...

Comment: Yes, but can use the `Eq` instance on tuples, which is pointwise equality: `(i,j) -> (i,j) == (boardSize, boardSize)`.

Comment: Note that haskell doesn't allow you to pattern matching on a variable value. So `(boardSize, 1)  -> True` this line actually captures whatever in the first place in the tuple to variable `boardSize` (shadowing the global one), instead of matching value 8 at the place.

Answer (score 3):

Names on the lefthand side of the `->` are patterns to match, not variables to be used. When matching patterns, a literal can only match itself, but a variable matches *anything*, and that value is assigned *to* the variable. This means that your `(1, boardSize)          -> True` matches any tuple where the first element is 1, and sets `boardSize` equal to the second element in the expression on the right-hand size.

---

It works the same as when you are defining a function, where `isCornerPos (i,j) = ...` assigns the two elements of the argument tuple to `i` and `j`, respectively, rather than trying to match the existing values of `i` and `j` against the argument. In fact, this is *exactly* the same as in the `case` expression, because the function definition uses syntactic sugar in place of a `case` match.

```
isCornerPos (i,j) = ...
```

is just short for

```
isCornerPos = \x -> case $x of
                (i,j) -> ...
```

---

The standard way of using `boardSize` would be to use a guard:

```
isCornerPos :: Postion -> Bool
isCornerPos (i,j) | i == 1 && j == 1 = True
                  | i == 1 && j == boardSize = True
                  | i == boardSize && j == 1 = True
                  | i == boardSize && j == BoardSize = True
                  | otherwise = False
```

Or combining this with pattern matching:

```
isCornerPos :: Postion -> Bool
isCornerPos (1,1) = True
isCornerPos (1,j) = j == boardSize
isCornerPos (i,1) = i == boardSize
isCornerPos (i,j) = i == boardSize && j == boardSize
```

I would define a helper function instead and write this without guards.

```
isCornerPos (i,j) = inCorner i && inCorner j
   where inCorner x = x == 1 || x == boardSize
```

Comment: My preferred bikeshed color: ```isCornerPos (i,j) = all (`elem` [1,boardSize]) [i,j]```.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching introduces *new* variables. You are redeclaring `boardSize` as a local, new variable. Use instead new variable names, and constrain them to be `boardSize` with a guard. E.g.

```
case (i, j) of
        (1, 1)                  -> True
        (1, y) | y == boardSize -> True
        (x, 1) | x == boardSize -> True
        (x, y) | x == boardSize && y == boardSize -> True 
        _ -> False
```

Note that the code above could be improved greatly. So many `True` and `False` hint at using `&&` or `||` instead.

As a hint, try `(some property of i) && (some property of j)` instead, if you want to simplify your code. Properties can involve `==` and `||` as needed. (For a more advanced solution, exploit `elem`)

Comment: What is the great solution with `elem` here? My preferred solution would be chepner's final suggestion, with the `inCorner` helper function.

Comment: @amalloy The same but with ``inCorner = (`elem` [1, boardSize])``. Not that great, but decent.